# javascript multidimensional array filter element

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var object = [ { model: 'aa', size: 250, count: 1 },
{ model: 'bb', size: 'XL', count: 1 },
{ model: 'aa', size: 250, count: -2 },
{ model: 'cc', size: 'S', count: 1 },
{ model: 'cc', size: 'S', count: 1 },
{ model: 'aa', size: 250, count: 1 },]
```

I'd like to combine the numbers of the same size as the model on the arrangement array.

```js
var object = [{
    model: 'aa',
    size: 250,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    model: 'bb',
    size: 'XL',
    count: 1
  },
  {
    model: 'aa',
    size: 250,
    count: -2
  },
  {
    model: 'cc',
    size: 'S',
    count: 1
  },
  {
    model: 'cc',
    size: 'S',
    count: 1
  },
  {
    model: 'aa',
    size: 250,
    count: 1
  },
]



var result = object.reduce(function(acc, val) {
  var o = acc.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.model == val.model && obj.size == val.size;
  }).pop() || {
    model: val.model,
    size: val.size,
    count: 0
  };
  o.count += val.count;
  acc.push(o);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

I did it like this, but did I do it correctly?
Below is what I want

```
object = [ { model: 'aa', size: 250, count: 0 },
{ model: 'bb', size: 'XL', count: 1 },
{ model: 'cc', size: 'S', count: 2 },]
```

Comment: Thank you for your question.
I shared the code I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group your array based on `model` and `size` in an object accumulator using `array#reduce` and sum up the `count`. Then extract all values using `Object.values()`.

```js
const data = [ { model: 'aa', size: 250, count: 1 }, { model: 'bb', size: 'XL', count: 1 }, { model: 'aa', size: 250, count: -2 }, { model: 'cc', size: 'S', count: 1 }, { model: 'cc', size: 'S', count: 1 }, { model: 'aa', size: 250, count: 1 },],
      result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
        const key = o.model + '|' + o.size;
        r[key] = r[key] || {...o, count: 0};
        r[key].count += o.count;
        return r;
      },{}));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and it has been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to achieve the result.

```js
var object = [
  { model: "aa", size: 250, count: 1 },
  { model: "bb", size: "XL", count: 1 },
  { model: "aa", size: 250, count: -2 },
  { model: "cc", size: "S", count: 1 },
  { model: "cc", size: "S", count: 1 },
  { model: "aa", size: 250, count: 1 },
];

const dict = {};

object.forEach((obj) => {
  const { model, size, count } = obj;
  if (dict[size]) {
    dict[size]["count"] = dict[size]["count"] + count;
  } else {
    dict[size] = { ...obj };
  }
});

const result = Object.values(dict);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```